# Can everyone in an Xbox Live Family Pack access DLC etc?

Tags: xbox-network

I've had an Xbox Live Gold subscription for over 10 years now but, since my partner has recently moved in, I'm looking at alternatives to see how best to share games and content. I have a massive collection of XBLA+On-Demand games as well as DLC but currently my partner can't play the full XBLA games etc. because her (Silver) account didn't purchase them.

If I change my account to an Xbox Live Family Pack (primary member) and hers to a secondary member, will she be able to have full access to my existing and future content?

Also, as a small bonus, we have 2 consoles (sparkling main and old and scaffy) and I was wondering if doing this will allow her to download my content on her Xbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK all the DLC I downloaded on my gold account, my brother with a silver account has access to on the *same* xbox.

As far as copying to another console goes, that's typically not allowed to prevent people from downloading the DLC to their friend's xbox as well as their own. [This page](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live/marketplace-and-purchasing/download-content) from the xboxlive site should help to answer any questions you have.

Comment: And does the same apply to XBLA games? Currently my partner can only play my XBLA games in trial mode. I'm hoping Family Pack would fix this.

Comment: "Q: If I purchase an Xbox LIVE Arcade game, does it belong to everyone in the family?

A: Purchased content such as games and movies are licensed both to the console it was purchased on, and the individual Gold member that purchased it. So if, for example, your child were to buy an Xbox LIVE Arcade game on your home console, anyone on your console can play it. Additionally, if they leave for college, they could recover their account on another Xbox 360 in their dorm room and be able to play the game when logged into their account from that Xbox 360." Basically, yes.